# Overlayitem objects constructor is undefined

Tags: java, android, web-services, google-maps

I'm going through a web service tutorial and have come across this last error I cannot fix.

I am getting an error on the itemOverlay object when calling the classes constructor that the constructor OverlayItem(Drawable) is undefined.

I dont really understand this as I'm supplying the relevant data to the constructor and I cant believe the constructor does not require any values to be passed to it?

This is the method that error is occurring on:

```
 MapActivity mapAct = (MapActivity)ctx;
        MapView map = (MapView)mapAct.findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setScrollBarStyle(MapView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(Boolean.TRUE);
        map.displayZoomControls(Boolean.TRUE);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(geoName.lat * 1E6), (int)(geoName.lng * 1E6));
        MapController mc = map.getController();
        mc.setZoom(17);
        mc.setCenter(point);
        mc.animateTo(point);

        List<Overlay> overlays = map.getOverlays();
        overlays.clear();

                    ***** ERROR on constructor*****
        OverlayItem items = new OverlayItem(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker));
        OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem(point, geoName.placeName, "" + geoName.postalCode);

        items.addOverlay(item);
        overlays.add(items);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you're confused. Look at the [`OverlayItem` documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/OverlayItem), and there's just a [single constructor](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/OverlayItem#OverlayItem%28com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
public OverlayItem(GeoPoint point,
                   java.lang.String title,
                   java.lang.String snippet)
```

So your *second* constructor call (for `item`) is fine, as that's passing in a point, title and snippet, but this one (for `items`):

```
new OverlayItem(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker))
```

is trying to *just* pass a `Drawable`... and there's no constructor with a siganture of

```
// This doesn't exist!
public OverlayItem(Drawable drawable)
```

Given the rest of your code, I suspect you *actually* wanted [`ItemizedOverlay`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay):

```
ItemizedOverlay items = new ItemizedOverlay(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker));
```

Rather than just change your code, you should take a step back and work out why you didn't spot this from the compiler error. It's giving you all the information you need to understand why your current code is wrong - although admittedly not the class that you should have been using instead.